# White-space between two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column as like given below

```
EB.Liter+'L'+EB.CC+'cc'+'-ci'+EB.BlockType+EB.Cylinders+
         (
       EB.EngBoreIn+'x'+
        EB.EngStrokeIn+';'+
        EB.EngBoreMetric+'x'+
    EB.EngStrokeMetric
         ) as EngineBase
```

This pull data something like this

```
1.3   L 1339    cc L 4 (2.87      x3.15      ;73.0      x80.0      )
```

but i am trying to get something like

```
1.3L 1339cc -ci L4 (2.87x3.15; 73.0x80.0)
```

may anyone please suggest if possible

i have tried something like this.

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.Liter))+'L'+LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.CC))+'cc'+'-  
ci'+LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.BlockType))+LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.Cylinders))+
        + (
       LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.EngBoreIn))+'x'+
        LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.EngStrokeIn))+';'+
        LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.EngBoreMetric))+'x'+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.EngStrokeMetric))
         ) as EBase
```

which get me result as below
    1.3L1339cc-ciL42.87x3.15;73.0x80.0

but correct output is as
    1.3L 1339cc -ciL4(2.87x3.15; 73.0x80.0)

Comment: What DB application are you using?

Comment: It looks like your data is being stored as strings having extra trailing spaces. So you have to trim them in order to achieve desired results. Concrete realization depends on DBMS you're using (`sql` is very general tag and doesn't provides such an information)

Comment: What dbms are you using? you can use replace function to replace ' ' with ''

Comment: SQL 2008..................I tried LTRIM and RTRIM But its not working out

Comment: Can you post what you have tried using `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` because that is the correct way to go.

Comment: add single quotes to the brackets which you want to print and add spaces in the string literals as well where needed. I think that solves your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify like this

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.Liter))+'L '+LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.CC))+'cc '+'-ci'+LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.BlockType))+LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.Cylinders))+
    + '('+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.EngBoreIn))+'x'+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.EngStrokeIn))+'; '+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.EngBoreMetric))+'x'+
    LTRIM(RTRIM(EB.EngStrokeMetric))
    +')' as EBase
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [trim](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) functionality to remove leading and trailing spaces. Your query would look like that then:

```
TRIM(EB.Liter) + 'L'+TRIM(EB.CC)+'cc'+'-ci'+TRIM(EB.BlockType)+TRIM(EB.Cylinders)+
(
TRIM(EB.EngBoreIn)+'x'+
TRIM(EB.EngStrokeIn)+';'+
TRIM(EB.EngBoreMetric)+'x'+
TRIM(EB.EngStrokeMetric)
) as EngineBase
```

Comment: @Gareth: hi. i have edited my question with what i tried. kindly suggest. thanks

Comment: trim is not sqlserver